# Changing the inner HTML of a div to a variable collected from user

Tags: javascript, local-storage, innerhtml

I have a site, which takes a html code block from the user, for the site [time.is](https://time.is/widgets) and then is supposed to show that later. The code is taken as a JavaScript Prompt and the stored in the local storage

```
let timeislink= prompt("Please enter the code as it is, with no spaces, or your clock might break");
localStorage.setItem("timeisperslink", timeislink);
```

And for adding it to the div, I take the local storage value, and store it in a variable and try to pass that under the .innerHTML function, but that doesn't seem to be working

```
function changetime(){
     let timedivneed= document.getElementById('timeisdynmdiv')
     let usetimeis= localStorage.getItem("timeisperslink")
     timedivneed.innerHTML+= usetimeis;
 }
```

Any help is appreciated

Edit:- #HTML of the page in which div has to be changed#

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <h2 id="timewish" onload="changetime()"></h2>
    
        <div id="timeisdynmdiv">
    
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Have removed unwanted things

Comment: add html code too

Comment: @RahulKumar Check it out now

Comment: Did you try checking a few values by using console.log()? Ex: console.log(usetimeis)

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that your script block is not located anywhere in the HTML. For best results, add your script block after the `<div>`. So:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <h2 id="timewish" onload="changetime()"></h2>
    
        <div id="timeisdynmdiv">
    
        </div>
        <script>
window.onload = function(){
          let timeislink= prompt("Please enter the code as it is, with no spaces, or your clock might break");
localStorage.setItem("timeisperslink", timeislink);
}
function changetime(){
     let timedivneed= document.getElementById('timeisdynmdiv')
     let usetimeis= localStorage.getItem("timeisperslink")
     timedivneed.innerHTML+= usetimeis;
 }
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Tell me if this doesn't work for you and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use window `load` event and put your logic to get localStorage data.

```
// Test mock to set data in localstorage
document.onreadystatechange = function(e) { 
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      console.log("readyState");
      localStorage.setItem("timeisperslink", "test data description");
    }
};


window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log("loaded");
  let timedivneed = document.getElementById('timeisdynmdiv')
  let usetimeis = localStorage.getItem("timeisperslink")
  timedivneed.innerHTML += usetimeis;
});
```